# book/openany, but start on right?

Tags: margins, layout

How can I avoid blank pages between chapters but start the book on a right page?

I’ve tried “openany”, but that starts the book on the left, so the margins are screwed up.

Thank you in advance!

For reference, this is the first page I get:
[image]

Comment: It does not it is presumably you viewer which in side-by-side mode shows the first page as a left page. Last I checked Adobe reader did this whereas Evince which I use on Linux shows the first page on the right leaving the left part blank as it should. So please start by explaining how exactly you come to the conclusion that this is a left page (note you are not the first with this confusion l

Comment: @daleif: I’m sure there’s something I’m missing, but the central pane is further to the left than to the right, which gives the appearance of a left page.

Comment: @daleif: Also, when I manually set margins to

Comment: First of, show code, not images. Secondly, without knowing the margin design of the document we don't know what to f this is the intent. Clearly in this image the right margin of the box where it says "part I" is larger than the left side (the shallow box is an indicator of marginpar data), and this is the traditional way to design a book, on right hand pages the right margin is normally larger than the left hand margin and vice versa. We have been over this many many times on this site

Answer (score 1):

The macro `\cleardoublepage` starts the following text on an odd numbered page.

```
% openanyprob.tex  SE 566313

\documentclass[openany]{book}

\begin{document}

Some title text.

\cleardoublepage

\chapter{First}
More text.
\chapter{Second}
Yet more text

\end{document}
```

It would have been helpful if you had provided an MWE (from `\documentclass...` to `\end{document}`) so that I didn't have to (wrongly) guess at what your code might be.